# Windows Shift-Tab Binding / Escape Sequence (Clink / Cmder / Conemu / readline)

Tags: windows, cmd, escaping, readline, conemu

I am trying to bind <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to a command in my `clink_inputrc` file.  (I've changed <kbd>Tab</kbd> to circular style completing, want <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to reverse it.)

The documentation gives a table "Binding special keys", but Tab is not an entry (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> is `` \e`# ``).  Does someone know the appropriate escape code, a reference for more extensive documentation on Windows escape codes, or a way to figure out the code for an arbitrary keypress/chord?

EDIT: Apologies, left off the documentation link: https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/master/docs/clink.md

Comment: Seems like that is not a ConEmu configuration question. But clink only! And what "documentation" you are refers?

Comment: @Maximus Doc link added, my mistake.  My question looks like a clink configuration question, but I think it's really more a question about how escape codes work on Windows ('way to figure out the code for an arbitrary keypress/chord'), and I thought that would be something that may have come up for ConEmu users.  Awesome job, and many thanks, on/for ConEmu, btw.

Comment: The link to `clink.md` currently points to a file that has nothing but the word "TODO"... This (older?) version contains the full manual text: https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/298113a61272afa3f646a912c97e2ce34da67597/docs/clink.md#file-locations

Answer (score 1):

I believe, right place to ask question about clink is [clink's issues](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues).

But, if the question was about ConEmu - you can use [GuiMacro](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/GuiMacro), for example `Keys("^+PgUp")` to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> keypress to the console. And of course you can bind that GuiMacro to any desired hotkey, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> for example.

[image: Using GuiMacro to send keypresses in ConEmu]